# How to make FL Studio read the variable tempo stored in MIDI files used in patterns?

Tags: midi, fl-studio

I don't know how to make FL Studio read the variable tempo stored in MIDI files that I used in patterns as it does already with the samples. I'm tired of making the tempo of MIDI files consistent so I can make it the same with FLStudio project tempo. Otherwise, this will cause polyphony issues in terms of music production.